# Take Query String stored in SQL and reformat as Json

Tags: sql-server, json, t-sql

I have a database (MS SQL) with a column that contains a query string. I want to take that query string and move it into a column that stores some settings in Json.

I could manually do this if it was only a few columns in one database, but this is part of a major upgrade that will be pushed out to over 50 sites. I'd like to have a T-SQL script that I could run on every database to perform this task for me.

Here's a sample of what the data will look like in the first column (as a query string):

```
KEY1=VALUE1&KEY2=VALUE2
```

I'd like to format that like so:

```
{"KEY1":"VALUE1","KEY2":"VALUE2"}
```

I'd appreciate any ideas you can throw my way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can use this

```
SELECT '{"' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@x, '=', '":"'), '&', '","') + '"}'
```

of course @x is your column I was testing with @x = N'KEY1=VALUE1&KEY2=VALUE2'

Comment: This get's me pretty much all the way there. Now I just have to take that and push it into the correct column for the JSON settings. Thanks!

Comment: Beat me to it and you had a much better answer than the road I was going down.  +1, great answer!